# How to get multiple random numbers in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to sample multiple records from big table randomly. Currently, a way I can go is to make random numbers in python and use them in sqlite3. Though I know random() of sqlite gives a random number, I don't know how to get (DISTINCT) multiple random numbers in sqlite. If I can make a table filled with random numbers, it would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many rows you want, you can use something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, etc FROM yourtable ORDER BY random() LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: In my case, a DISTINCT keyword is not needed, but it works very well! Thanks a lot!